# xcode7 ui testing: how does xcode determines that method is Test

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode-ui-testing

How does xcode determines that method is uiTest? 
Look at the pic:

[image: Similar methods works different: only one of them is defined as uitest]

Comment: my problem was in renamed target and some magic. i just clone repo again and reboot my xcode and it works fine.

Comment: by the way. if point of run method did not shown try: clean project, delete derived data, and !! wait utill xcode finish indexing files. I hope, this info will help somebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode has two criteria for determining if something is a test.

1. The class must inherit from `XCTestCase`
2. The method must start with `test`

Note that the class does not need to inherit *directly* from `XCTestCase`, but could be a grandchild. Also note that `test` is case sensitive.